# Suggest an app for reading PDF and CHM

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android, pdf, ebook-reader

I have seen apps that read CHM or PDF but not both. I need an app that reads PDF as well as CHM quickly and smoothly. I tried OliveOffice but there are issues with landscape mode. Is there any other ?

Comment: EzPDF is a realy nice PDF Reeder.

Comment: For PDFs I recommend Mantano Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) reads chm's and almost anything

Comment: I confirm that Moon Reader can open both PDF and CHM. It can also open epub and other formats.

Comment: Meanwhile even Mobi. Almost nothing left except for DRM -- which is not the author's fault (trouble with Adobe not reacting on his queries). I use that app almost for 2 years now, amazing development for a one-man-show!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your PDF's to CHM:

http://www.freepdfconvert.com/convert_help_file_to_pdf.asp

As you said [OliveOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.olivephone.edit)

or have you tried: [iReader](http://uk.androlib.com/android.application.com-chaozh-ireader-zxwi.aspx)

Here is an e-book reader list if you want a 4th option:

http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=70921